# I want the link/name to show of the folder I currently have open in embedded library as a web part,

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, document-library

In Embedded library as a web part, I want the link/name to show the folder I currently have open.

Similar to the library itself showing both links and name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you have described in your question is called `Document Library Breadcrumb`.

The `Document Library Breadcrumb` is working in document library itself but only show the current parent and child

[image]

**But Unfortunately**, it's not working in case  you tried to add the Document Library to a page as a web part *(it's your case)*

---

**The alternative workarounds**

1. Using **JSLink** by downloading the `FolderNavigation.js` file from [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Folder-661709eb). Check the detailed deployment steps [SharePoint 2013: Breadcrumb for list/library](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-folder-navigation-for.html)

**[OutPut]**

[image]

2. Using a free CodePlex tool, download F[ull Folder Path In SharePoint  Library Breadcrumb](http://fullpathbreadcrumb.codeplex.com/)
3. Using JQery, check the details at [Creating breadcrumbs in Sharepoint 2013 Document Library Pages and List Views](http://hardwiredmedia.com/creating-breadcrumbs-sharepoint-2013-document-library-pages/)